# How to block an IP, if getting many http/apache/mysql requests in a second

Tags: mysql, http, security

if some one tried force burst attack on my website. how can i block their IP address.

i mean, i want to block an IP if, getting many http/Apache/SQL requests per second. how can i prevent those force burst attacks

**Linux Server**

thank in advance

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [sf]

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35773/how-to-block-an-ip-if-getting-many-http-requests-in-a-second

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess you can add something like:

```
order allow,deny
deny from <ip address>
allow from all
```

Or depending upon your operating system you can add a rule to your iptables.

For example, [here is how you would do it in ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Blocking_Traffic).

Comment: @devid yes i am in linux server.but how can i know their IP address.

Comment: I think you can use the ntop utility (like top, but for network) to see traffic by IP address.  You might need to install the appropriate package for your distro.

Comment: The IP addresses of all the users who have visited your website are in your log files.  You will probably find these in `/var/log/apache2/` or `/var/log/httpd/`.  You can find how many requests each IP address has been doing recently with something like this: `tail -1000 access_log | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -50`.